# Result set larger than one row when Corda node use postgresql and schema

Tags: corda

I'm currently trying to have 2 node (one notary , one normal node) using the same Postgresql DB for storing data (instead of the embedded H2), but with a different schema for each (node schema, notary schema) .

Ah , I'm using the non-enterprise version btw, version 4.3 .

The notary node is the first one to start, it creates the needed tables in the notary schema , all seems fine there .

But when the 'normal' node boot, it crash saying :

```
[ERROR] 10:17:50+0000 [main] changelog.ChangeSet. - Change Set migration/node-core.changelog-postgres-blob.xml::modify checkpoint_value column type::R3.Corda failed.  Error: Migration failed for change set mig │
│      Reason:                                                                                                                                                                                                      │
│           master.changelog.json : liquibase.precondition.core.SqlPrecondition@7c682e26 : Result set larger than one row                                                                                           │
│  {changeSet=migration/node-core.changelog-postgres-blob.xml::modify checkpoint_value column type::R3.Corda, databaseChangeLog=master.changelog.json}                                                              │
│ [ERROR] 10:17:50+0000 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Exception during node registration: Could not create the DataSource: Migration failed for change set migration/node-core.changelog-postgres-blob.xml: │
│      Reason:                                                                                                                                                                                                      │
│           master.changelog.json : liquibase.precondition.core.SqlPrecondition@7c682e26 : Result set larger than one row                                                                                           │
│  [errorCode=14m37zv, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.3/14m37zv]                                                                                                                                   │
[ERROR] 10:17:50+0000 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Exception during node startup: net.corda.core.utilities.Try$Failure cannot be cast to net.corda.core.utilities.Try$Success [errorCode=rmnkpl, moreInf │
```

The node.conf I have for the notary is the following :

```
dataSourceProperties: {
    dataSourceClassName="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
    dataSource.url="jdbc:postgresql://psql-path:5432/postgres?currentSchema=notary"
    dataSource.user="dbUser"
    dataSource.password="xxxxxx"
}
```

And the one for the 'normal' node is :

```
dataSourceProperties: {
    dataSourceClassName="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
    dataSource.url="jdbc:postgresql://psql-path:5432/postgres?currentSchema=node"
    dataSource.user="dbUser"
    dataSource.password="xxxxxx"
}
```

So as you can see, the only difference is the ?currentSchema value .

Am I missing something ?

EDIT :

in the [doc](https://docs.corda.net/node-database.html#postgresql) , they are saying :

> If your PostgresSQL database is hosting multiple schema instances (using the JDBC URL currentSchema=my_schema) for different Corda nodes, you will need to create a hibernate_sequence sequence object manually for each subsequent schema added after the first instance. Corda doesn’t provision Hibernate with a schema namespace setting and a sequence object may be not created. Run the DDL statement and replace my_schema with your schema namespace:

I have done that and when connecting to the db , I can see taht for both schema I have tables created . Though for the notary I have 32 tables and only 26 for the 'normal' node .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic case of [documentation overlooking](https://docs.corda.net/node-database.html#postgresql) , the solution is :

> If your PostgresSQL database is hosting multiple schema instances (using the JDBC URL currentSchema=my_schema) for different Corda nodes, you will need to create a hibernate_sequence sequence object manually for each subsequent schema added after the first instance. Corda doesn’t provision Hibernate with a schema namespace setting and a sequence object may be not created. Run the DDL statement and replace my_schema with your schema namespace:

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use different schemes for different nodes. But i failed. Because there are some automatically-created tables without scheme. So i decided to use different database instances on the same db server.

I think this method might relieve your pain a little bit.

Comment: owh really ? So far did not noticed any issues with my setup (1 schema per nodes) . Can you tell me more about which tables are causing you troubles ?